# confused about the Kubernetes unnormal tolerations

Tags: kubernetes

when one pod has below tolerations.

```
  tolerations:
  - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoExecute
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    operator: Exists
```

why it can be scheduled to the node with below taints.
**`Runtime=true:NoSchedule`**

And I also searched the kubernetes documents. Generally one tolerations group will include the 'key', so how does below works?

```
 - effect: NoSchedule
    operator: Exists
```

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the issue,

I have tainted the node  `gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-2ixm` with `Runtime=true:NoSchedule`

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-2ixm   Ready    <none>   10d   v1.26.6-gke.1700
gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-ncy0   Ready    <none>   10d   v1.26.6-gke.1700
gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-o537   Ready    <none>   10d   v1.26.6-gke.1700

$ kubectl taint nodes gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-2ixm Runtime=true:NoSchedule
node/gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-2ixm tainted
```

Then I have created a deployment without any tolerations, so the pods are not scheduled with nodes with taints:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE                                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-deployment-7f456874f4-95x66   1/1     Running   0          34s   10.24.2.6    gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-o537   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-7f456874f4-9sj68   1/1     Running   0          34s   10.24.0.12   gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-ncy0   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-7f456874f4-f4s98   1/1     Running   0          34s   10.24.0.13   gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-ncy0   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-7f456874f4-zbgp9   1/1     Running   0          34s   10.24.2.7    gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-o537   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-7f456874f4-zs4js   1/1     Running   0          34s   10.24.0.11   gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-ncy0   <none>           <none>
```

Later I have added the tolerations given by you and 2 pods have scheduled on the node with applied taints : (I have deleted the existing deployment and deployed after adding tolerations)

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE                                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-deployment-6d998db8f-58wr2   1/1     Running   0          6s    10.24.1.7    gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-2ixm   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-6d998db8f-62dcm   1/1     Running   0          6s    10.24.2.8    gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-o537   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-6d998db8f-srcmg   1/1     Running   0          6s    10.24.0.14   gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-ncy0   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-6d998db8f-wv48m   1/1     Running   0          6s    10.24.1.6    gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-2ixm   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-6d998db8f-zbck2   1/1     Running   0          6s    10.24.0.15   gke-cluster-4-default-pool-8ad24f8f-ncy0   <none>           <none>
```

So the tolerations and taints are working fine so the issue is with the resource itself, it can be due to below reasons:

1.Insufficient resources on nodes such as CPU or memory check those with kubectl describe command.

2.Double check the taints and tolerations if there are any other taints or tolerations that are stopping the pod to schedule.

3.Check if you have any nodeselectors and affinity rules that prevent pods from scheduling the node.

For further debugging add the describe command of pod and node. Attaching a [blog](https://foxutech.com/kubernetes-taints-and-tolerations-explained/) written by motoskia for your reference.